# SceneKit - Modifying SCNGeometrySource dynamically without creating a new SCNGeometry

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have created a **SCNGeometrySource** that is initialized with a **MTLBuffer** and dynamically updating the buffer based on user interaction (e.g. drawing on the screen). What I want to do is to be able to render the node containing this geometry efficiently without having to recreate the underlying geometry every time. It doesn't look like **SCNGeometry** was designed to be modified based on the properties that it has.

Is there a better way to accomplish this other than what I'm currently doing? Or should I just render the **MTLBuffer** directly using the command encoder without using **SCNGeometry**?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the geometry source is backed by a Metal buffer that you can modify with compute shaders, why are you creating a new `SCNGeometry`?

Comment: Well, I'm modifying the Metal buffer via CPU (I'm adding more vertex data to it) and not using a compute shader.